# Which is better to generate the WS client from the WSDL URL or from the WSDL file?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I am using a wsdl file sent to me via email to generate a WS client application but I wonder if it is better to have the WSDL hosted on a server and to use an URL to request it.

Actually, I requested the URL but apparently this WSDL don't have one and I can ask to create an Url for the wsdl if it is really necessary.

Can you tell me please what are the benefits of using the WSDL Url to create a WS client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not difference for you how to generate WS client. In both cases this is just WSDL document, no matter where it located is.

I see only one benefit direct accessible WSDL against WSDL file - WSDL will be always actual and and all web service changes will be reflected to WSDL document.

If you using axis 2, you can try call your webservice with ?wsdl suffix to get WSDL document

if this your webservice url

```
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/StockQuoteService
```

This is wsdl location

```
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/StockQuoteService?wsdl
```

Comment: thank you Georgy, so if the developers modify the WSDL in there server, will my application consider the changes automatically ?

Comment: No, your application won't consider changes automatically. :D

Comment: kingAm right, @Tanboula you need regenerate your WS client every time WSDL changed

Comment: Thank you for your responses, so there aren't really advantages to use the wsdl URL in the ws client generation.